# How to handle deleting databases in Couch across multiple clients?

Tags: database, optimization, couchdb, database-replication, pouchdb

Within CouchDB it's sometimes the case that eventually you'll probably have more deleted documents within a database than active documents. After a while this becomes somewhat nonoptimal, as you're syncing more deleted document data than anything else.

[The official documentation recommends periodically destroying the databases in order to get around this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/maintenance/performance.html#delete-operation), but I've noticed that all that happens when doing this is that a client with a local copy of the database (e.g. if you have a database named "username" that's designed to replicate to a client device via Pouch), when it sees the blank database, refills it back up, deleted document records and all.

Short of changing the database name every time, is there any way to signal to other Couch instances that they shouldn't repopulate the new fresh and clean database, and instead take it as a new database entirely? Or, in fact, any other solution at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have bidirectional replication then the "other side" will replicate all the deleted docs back to the new DB.  The only two options I can think of are to have a new database (with a new name, which is what the docs you linked to probably meant), or to use [filtered replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#filterfun) so the client doesn't push up deleted docs (or doesn't push up deleted docs older than a certain point).

The latter of these options is significantly more complex than the former.

Comment: Having a new database with a new name was something I was trying to avoid, as I'd then have to somehow get the database name across each time. Not that that's difficult, just not ideal.

Filtered replication might be of use, but without the deleted docs, an older client that has non-deleted copies of the now-deleted documents would just put the full documents back into the database (that's a bit hard to follow but it made sense in my head!).

Comment: Yes, your filtering would need to include logic so that it only filtered deleted docs that had been deleted long enough that you were sure they were deleted everywhere.  The database rename, yes, would require you to parameterize your DB name in all clients and have a way to update them - as you identified though, that's quite simple to do.